# Display Multiple Histograms in the same Panel using Graphics R

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to print multiple histograms in the same window in R. I am using R Studio. I can only use the built in graphics package. I have been unable to find a solution to my problem on here already.

I am trying to create histograms of the iris data set.

For example:

one histogram for sepal width, another for sepal length, and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout [`mfrow`](https://www.google.se/search?q=mfrow&client=ubuntu&hs=hg&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=gLJQVem6D6XpywPQ3YDICQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1105) or [`layout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198767/how-to-annotate-across-or-between-plots-in-multi-plot-panels-in-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Backlin commented above, you can use the `par()` function and `mfrow` option to control subplots:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

hist(iris$Sepal.Width)
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
hist(iris$Petal.Width)
hist(iris$Petal.Length)
```